# How to persist recurring transactions in core data and present it in a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, eventkit

Swift2.2 / iOS9.3

I am fairly new to programming. I am working on an app to plan transactions ahead. For user friendly experience I want to give an option of recurring transactions. Furthermore, I want to display transactions in a `tableview`, fetched from `coreData`. But I can't seem to get my head around it. What if the recurrence is never ending, how to solve this in the core data model. Or should I solve this (partially) in `EventKit`? Any suggestions to approach this problem would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You would most likely want to handle recurring events within `EventKit`, using the [EKRecurrenceRule](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKRecurrenceRuleClassRef/). With this, you could potentially set an `occurrenceCount`, or an `endDate` if your wanted, but you don't necessarily have to.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed this was one of the options I recon it is the way to go. Exept I still can't grasp the concept of combining a transaction entry in coredata with EKrecurrenceRule and presenting individual recurring transactions in a tableview. Is the right way to fetch my (recurring) transactions from coredata, then apply EKrecurrenceRule, then populate a new array and then populate the tableview with this new array? Any suggestions for tutorials would also help. Thanks again!